# Getting viabilityChanged error while integration of Starscream Websocket lib

Tags: sockets, websocket, starscream, tclientsocket

Please check this below code. Every time I am receiving this **case: .viablityChanged** I don't know what is this error and why it's coming and how to solve this. I am using the Starscream Websocket lib.

[image: !]

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you find any solution?